Mount Network Drive SwiftUI
    import SwiftUI

    struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var username: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""
    @State private var connectionStatus: String = ""
    
    @discardableResult func shell(_ command: String, withPassword password: String) -> (String?,       Int32) {
    // Erstelle neuen Prozess und lege den Pfad fest
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
        
    // Konstruiere das Kommando zur Nutzung von sudo mit Passwort
    let sudoCommand = "echo \(password) | sudo -S \(command)"
        
    // "-c" Argument lässt nachfolgenden Befehl als Bash-Befehl ausführen
    task.arguments = ["-c", sudoCommand]
        
    // Pipe für Ausgabe und Fehlermeldung
    let pipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.standardError = pipe
    // Starte Prozess
    task.launch()
    // Lese gesamte Ausgabe
    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    // Konvertiere Ausgabe in einen String, falls möglich
    let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    task.waitUntilExit()
    return (output, task.terminationStatus)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
    VStack {
    Text("Connect Network Drive")
    .font(.title)
    .bold()
    .padding()
           
    TextField("Username", text: $username)
    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
    .padding()
            
    SecureField("Password", text: $password)
               .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .padding()
            
            Button(action: {
                runScript()
            }) {
                Text("Connect").font(.body)
            }
            .padding()
            
            Text(connectionStatus)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .padding()
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    func runScript() {
        // Pfad zum Mountpunkt und zum Netzlaufwerk
        let mountPoint = "~/Desktop/DriveH"
        let networkPath = "//\(username):\(password)@server/Pfad" // Passen Sie den Netzwerkpfad an
        
        // Erstellen des Verzeichnisses, falls es nicht existiert
        let mkdirCommand = "mkdir -p \(mountPoint)"
        let mountCommand = "mount_smbfs \(networkPath) \(mountPoint)"
        
        // Führen Sie den Befehl zum Erstellen des Verzeichnisses aus
        let mkdirResult = shell(mkdirCommand, withPassword: password)
        if mkdirResult.1 != 0 {
            connectionStatus = "Failed to create mount point: \(mkdirResult.0 ?? "Unknown error")"
            return
        }
        
        // Führen Sie den Befehl zum Mounten des Netzlaufwerks aus
        let mountResult = shell(mountCommand, withPassword: password)
        if mountResult.1 == 0 {
            connectionStatus = "Network drive connected successfully."
        } else {
            connectionStatus = "Failed to connect network drive: \(mountResult.0 ?? "Unknown error")"
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}



I am trying to mount a network drive via a Swift UI. But unfortunately I only get the following response "Operation not permitted", can anyone help me here?
I have already tried to run it as "sudo", but that didn't work properly either. But it could also be that I programmed it incorrectly.
I have already tried to mount it via a bash script so that the button calls the bash script, but unfortunately this resulted in the same error message.

Did the bash script work from the terminal? Note that when you use Process it inherits the privileges and environment settings from its parent and that parent is your app so if the app is sandboxed this could be an issue. I don’t know if this is a problem but I would be careful with using tilde or any such shortcuts in your path strings unless you have verified it translates to the right path.

I have replaced tilde with a variable.
In the meantime, I still get the same error message, but it is now in green and not red
I also removed the "sudo" part from the code, because my normal user has the authorization to mount network drives

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

It's not allowed to run shell scripts in a sandbox environment. Well, it is possible under certain circumstances but Process is strictly forbidden.
However NetFSMountURLAsync in the NetFS framework does work in a sandbox if you specify the mount point somewhere in the application container for example in the Application Support folder.
Important: You have to enable Outgoing Connections (Client) in the sandbox settings.
This is an example
import NetFS

var requestID : AsyncRequestID?
let url = URL(string: "smb://MyServer.local/myvolume")!
let userName = "user"
let password = "pass"   
let mountPoint = URL.applicationSupportDirectory

NetFSMountURLAsync(url as CFURL,
                   mountPoint as CFURL,
                   userName as CFString,
                   password as CFString,
                   nil,
                   nil,
                   &requestID,
                   DispatchQueue.global()
) { status, requestID, mountpoints in
    if status != 0 && status != -128 {
        print("Shared Volume mount at \(url.path) failed with status: \(status)")
    }
}


Hey so i tried to buid the function as you told me to, but i receive the Error Message : "Failed to produce diagnostic for expression"
To be fair im super new at Swift and i dont know what i can do to solve this problem.
I am just trying to create a Programm which Mounts a network drive

Put the code I suggested into runScript replacing the existing code, then delete the let userName = "user" and let password = "pass" lines, rename userName as username in the NetFSMountURLAsync call and change the literal smb://… string to your actual data. The import line must be on the same level as import SwiftUI.
